# How can I record audio and save it in hex format for the purpose of send it to a ble device in android?

Tags: android, hex, audiorecord, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to record audio in my application and send it to a ble device. I think that the data should be in hex format to be received by a ble device. In which format I have to record audio in this case? How can I save it as hex values? And finally how can I send this data to a ble device? Can anyone help me with an example?

Comment: Always remember to Google first. Googling your question title turns up results like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404998/how-to-send-an-audio-hex-file-to-ble-device and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101685/send-a-pcm-file-on-ios-to-ble-device

Comment: I have already gone through these links. I am a fresher in android and ble. I didn't get an idea of how to start from the mentioned examples