# How can I convert wav audio file to hex values in android?

Tags: android, hex, wav, audio-recording, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am recording and save audio in wav format.

I want to convert that audio file into hex values in order to send to a Bluetooth low energy device. How can I convert my .wav file into hex? 
I want to print corresponding hex values of my audio file. How can I do this?

Comment: What does your Bluetooth device accept? PCM samples?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem What do you really want to do? To send the file? You don't need hex for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404998/how-to-send-an-audio-hex-file-to-ble-device here it is mentioned about audio wavfile  converted into hexfile. I want to know how to do that conversion

Answer (score 2):

Open the file in binary, send across to other device and save that file. As simple as that.